# Chrome crashes Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, logout

12.04. Soon after I start Google Chrome stable version, it crashes Ubuntu--whole system goes back to logout screen.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling google-chrome-stable, beta, and chromium. tried deleting ./config/google-chrome.  no luck.  Firefox works fine.

How to

Comment: what is your output if run in a terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

After last my update my *Chrome* now also tested cause Ubuntu logout trap *:D*
Ok, need to say also *Gnome* was logged into the *Fallback* session.

Then I go to restart, log into *Recovery* session.
First run point "*dpkg repair* " and wait for all my filesystems will be mounted.
Said ***yes*** for "mount" notification.

Next run point "*Drop to Root Shell* ".

Run (NVIDIA + GDM):

1. `su username`
2. `wget <latest OR needed display driver href>` OR `cd <DOWNLOAD FOLDER>`
3. `sudo sh ./<DISPLAY-DRIVER-INSTALLER-NAME.run>`
4. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`  ( a mostly Gnome fallback troubleshooter )
5. `exit` for usersession `exit` for root session and backing to Recovery menu.

Now run *Resume Normal Boot* OR exit and reboot the machine completely.
Have fun! :)